# While Using PLink Only First Command Is Executing

Tags: putty, plink

I want to connect putty using plink and want to run some specific commands which is present in text file. But I can see only first command getting executed. Do I need to give any command separating literal?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Solutions that I used.

1. Sending one line command with `&&` or `&`
2. If script is big, send it with pscp and run on remote host with single command/

I beleive there is the third way. Just execute script under `-m` option :)